# I want to restrict some of the view controller to landscape in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios6

I'm trying to restrict one view controller which on top of UINavigationController.  To do that i've created a UINavigationController subclass and implemented 2 methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];}
```

I want the first viewcontroller on top of UINavigationController(which is Root View Controller) should be in portrait mode and the next view controller which i'm pushing from the root view controller should be Landscape mode(ONLY).

So i'm overriding those two methods in both view controllers.
In the root view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return NO;}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;}
```

In the next view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;}
```

Its working fine but not completely. For the first time when I push the view controller its showing in portrait mode(Not restricting to landscape as I expected) and once I rotate the device/simulator and its working fine and restricting to landscape only.

Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

Call this one in the `viewWillAppear` will explicitly tell the device to jump to the portrait orientation.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:") withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

I don't think this is the right solution. But if you got no other options, you can use this.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks buddy, I have spent more than one day to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

U `present` `new` `controller` :

```
SecondViewController *objSecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:objSecondViewController animated:NO completion:^{}];
```

In `new` `controller` :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. Just try using this :

1) **`YourApp-Info.plist`**

- Add one more array for Supported interface orientations
- Add your required orientation to this dictionary

**Refer below screenshot :**

[image]

2) **`Project Target`**

- Select the required orientation from Supported Interface Orientations

**Refer below screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: HOW THIS WILL RESTRICT TO PARTICULAR CONTROLLER ?

Answer (score -2):

`UIViewController` have the following function. You can implement this in your view controller where you want to restict portrait orientation.

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        // Return YES for supported orientations

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply suresh, but in ios6 that method doesn't invoke.  Thats why we are using other two methods.